# Can't see my results in Ionic3 with SqLite, even though it recognizes number of rows

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic3

there, I'm new to Ionic and trying to learn my way with SQLite in it.
I get success in creating and droping tables, and after using INSERT INTO in a table I try to read its contents... That's when things get weird: I get a response like this:

```
{"rows":{"length":5},"rowsAffected":0}
```

Here's the code:

```
    let sqlait: SQLite = new SQLite();
    return sqlait.create({
      name: 'contacomigo.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then(
      (db: SQLiteObject) => {
        return db.executeSql('SELECT ' + Conta.col_id + ' FROM ' + Conta.tabela, {})
          .then((data) => {
            d.alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
              contas.push(data.rows.item(i));
            }
          })
          .catch(e => d.alert(e));
      }
      ).catch(e => { d.alert(e) });

    if (contas.length == 0) {
      contas.push('0 contas!');
    } else {
      d.alert(JSON.stringify(contas))
    }
    return contas.toString();
  }
```

I would really love to learn that it's something ridiculous that I'm missing... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the results like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[0].rows.length; i++) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming here! The way it is (in the question), I DO GET the objects using "contas" in the .html file, but only there! I can't get to see the data in the array contas inside the .ts file... I tried that "data[0].rows" solution you sugested, but with no success and the message "Cannot read property ROWS of undefined"... in the .html file, the list of "contas" comes empty.